# Avoid remote website inclusion

Tags: apache, http, inclusion, botnet, client-side-attacks

I recently saw a few malicious domains including my website pages.

I initially suspected of iframe inclusion, but I already had `Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` configured in my *httpd.conf*.

Other ideas were about malware Javascript including remote pages in the DOM, or even external DNS pointing to my server IP (however, I have name-based virtual hosting on). None of them have been proved.

Investigating on remote domain and looking at apache logs showed us the reality: the malicious remote server made http requests to us, for each request it received, then sent back the result to its clients, actually "mirroring" our website!

I lack ideas on how to stop it. So I blocked its User-Agent completely, via apache conf: **`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)`**

Hope I explained myself. Is there a smarter way to stop such a bad behavior from other domains like them, in the future?